# How to fetch models with joined models in Bookshelf?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have this 1-to-many data model for stocks and snapshots.

```
// stock.js
var bookshelf = require('../config');
var Snapshot = require('./snapshot');

var Stock = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'stocks',
   hasTimestamps: true,

   snapshots: function() {
     return this.hasMany(Snapshot);
   }
});
module.exports = bookshelf.model('Stock', Stock);
```

Each stock has many data snapshots. A snapshot belongsTo a Stock:

```
var bookshelf = require('../config');
var Stock = require('./stock');
var Snapshot = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'snapshots',
   hasTimestamps: true,

   stock: function() {
     return this.belongsTo(Stock);
   }
});
module.exports = bookshelf.model('Snapshot', Snapshot);
```

However, when I try to fetch multiple Snapshots from a Stock like this:

```
// report stock
var bookshelf = require('./config');

var Stock = require('./models/stock');
var Snapshot = require('./models/snapshot');
var Promise = require("bluebird");

Stock.fetchAll({
  withRelated: ['snapshots'],
  debug: true
})
.then(function(collection) {
    return collection.mapThen(function(model) {
      return model.toJSON();
    })
})
.then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
})
.finally(function(r) {
  return bookshelf.knex.destroy();
})
.catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I don't see any snapshots:

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [],
  sql: 'select "stocks".* from "stocks"' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [ 1 ],
  sql: 'select "snapshots".* from "snapshots" where "snapshots"."stock_id" in (?)' }
[ { id: 1,
    name: '...',
    symbol: '...',
    created_at: 1460285493918,
    updated_at: 1460285493918,
    snapshots: [] } ]
```

I would expect to see snapshots and a `join` query. However, the snapshots array is empty. What do I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `bookshelf.plugin("registry")`, you'll need to link your [relations](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry#relations) by string name.

```
var bookshelf = require('../config')

var Stock = bookshelf.model('Stock', {

  tableName: 'stocks',

  hasTimestamps: true,

  snapshots: function () {

    return this.hasMany('Snapshot')
  }
})

var Snapshot = bookshelf.model('Snapshot', {

  tableName: 'snapshots',

  hasTimestamps: true,

  stock: function () {

    return this.belongsTo('Stock')
  }
})
```

Comment: hmm.. seems not to fetch the associations, at least in the code example I try here: https://github.com/mulderp/stock_tracker

Comment: `bookshelf.model` takes 3 arguments; `ModelName`, `protoProps`, and `staticProps`. Your example is passing the `ModelName` and a `Model` constructor. Instead of using `bookshelf.Model.extend` to create your `Model`, let `bookshelf.model` do it for you.